# How to write a program in C#, which searches through object list by any of the movie data (using loops)?

Tags: c#, list, loops, object, search

I am doing simple console app in C# which has ability to search through movie library (object list) by any movie data (data type) using loop.

```
public static List<Movie> Movies= new List<Movie>() 
{
(1, "The Shawshank Redemption", "Drama", 1994, "Tim Robbins", "9.3/10")
(2, "The Godfather", "Crime", 1972, "Marlon Brando", "9.2/10")
}
```

Try smth but lost idea:

```
public static void Search()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter input value: ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            userInput.ToLower();

            //foreach (var m in movies)
            //{
            //    if
            //        (f.ID.ToString().Contains(userInput.ToLower()) || f.Title.Contains(userInput.ToLower()) || f.Year.ToString().Contains(userInput.ToLower()) || f.Genre.Contains(userInput.ToLower()) || f.mainActor.Contains(userInput.ToLower()) || f.IMDB_Rating.Contains(userInput.ToLower()))

            foreach (Film f in movies)
            {
                if(f.ToString().Contains(userInput))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value find!\n");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{f.MovieForPrintOut}");
                }
            }
```

Already spent hours looking for best solution on youtube, stackoverflow, openAI, etc.
Thanks in advance,
greeting.

Comment: What is `Film.ToString()` returning? does it contain `userInput`? I bet not ;)

Comment: `Film` or `Movie` which is it? - But anyways: Maybe consider having a Database system make the search easier (and more performant).

Comment: What problem are you seeing? Have you tried examining the output of `f.ToString()` in your loop?

Comment: Also `f.Genre.Contains(userInput.ToLower())` is the same as  `"Drama".Contains("drama")`, which is false always (upper/lower case "D", "d").

Comment: `userInput.ToLower();` doesn't do anything. Strings in c# are immutable. `ToLower` *returns* the string in lowercase, so if you want to capture that, you'd need to do: `userInput = userInput.toLower();`

Comment: Your list is named `Movies`, but in your (commented) code it's `movies`...? And the variable is named `m`, but in the loop body it's `f`...? Please post samples that compile (unless there's a specific compilation issue you're asking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think the idea you were stating was something like the code below.

Note that in some cases we probably want to do an exact match, like for `Year` or `Id`. Otherwise, there is no case-insensitive `Contains` method, but `IndexOf` takes a comparer, so we can use that method to check for partial matches in a case-insensitive way (it returns the index of the string to match if it was found, otherwise `-1`).

```
// Takes in a string that's used to find a list of movies that match
// The list of movies is returned
public static List<Movie> Search(string input)
{
    List<Movie> matches = new List<Movie>();

    foreach (var movie in Movies)
    {
        if (movie.Id.ToString().Equals(input) ||
            movie.Title.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
            movie.Year.ToString().Equals(input) ||
            movie.Genre.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
            movie.MainActor.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
            movie.IMDBRating.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            matches.Add(movie);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<Movie> crimeMovies = Search("Crime");
```

This should get you started, but the results will be a little unpredictable. Even though the Genre "Crime" was what the user wanted, any movie with "Crime" in the name will be returned, so you might get a Romantic Comedy named "Crimes of Passion" in the results. Something to think about...

Comment: Thanks for help, find solution to my problem. Understand your point but task has explicit instruction to do that.